# Vue-cli multisite structure

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have to make a multi-site project with 4 different domains but with a lot of components in common. For now I'm just focus on the design, working with this fast structure:

```
src
  main.js with require('./domainX/main.js')
    domain1/..
    domain2/..
    domain3/..
    domain4/..
    common/components and scripts
    assets/...
```

What could be the best approach to do this?

- Set the current approach
- Split chunks with webpack
- Have different vue projects and upload all the components and scripts in private npm